# Is C++ double precision only 3 digit?

Tags: c++, precision

I wrote a small program and ran on wintel.  I get 3 if x is double and 4 if x is defined as long double.  Does it mean these types are only accurate to 3 or 4 decimals ?

Thanks

```
double x = 1;
long double f = 0.1;

while (x+f-f == x) f /= 10;

int precision = 1-log10(f);
```

Comment: Can't use equality operator with floats/doubles. They don't work as expected.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and go read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Why not `while( x+f != x)` ?  (Quite a different result)

Comment: @Dialecticus - please don't spread that misconception. Equality operators work just fine for floats and doubles. Calculations often don't give the result that naive users (or not-so-naive users) expect, so the **correct** result of an equality test gives an answer that the user didn't expect. That's not the fault of the equality test, but of the calculation that led up to it.

Comment: @PeteBecker how is this different from "They don't work as expected"?

Comment: @Dialecticus - the problem is in the calculated values, not in the equality operator.

Answer (score 7):

No.  A `double` is normally an [IEEE 754 double-precision floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), meaning it has a 52-bit fraction field.  Including the implicit leading 1 gives 53 significant bits, or approximately 16 decimal digits:

log<sub>10</sub>(2<sup>53</sup>) ≈ 15.955

Assuming you're on an Intel platform, `long double` is usually an [80-bit floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) with a 64-bit significand.  That gives about 19 decimal digits worth of precision:

log<sub>10</sub>(2<sup>64</sup>) ≈ 19.266

Comment: (Marginal nitpicking [just before *some,* khm, numeric engineers come and downvote]: it's worth noting that the implicit bit may not be 1 for some special cases.)

Comment: For denorms, yeah, but those might have as little as one significant bit.  I don't think that case is relevant to the question.

Comment: Numeric engineers? Nice euphemism. :) [+1 to the answer]

Comment: @NPE (In fact, one particular, well-known person, whom I do not wish to mention.)

Comment: @H2CO3: LOL, let's leave it at that. :)

Comment: The 80 bit wide `long double` was phased out after Visual Studio 6. For 64-bit targets all floating point calculations are done in the SSE unit, i.e. `double` as well as `long double` are now 64 bits.

Comment: `sizeof(long double)` is 16 in Clang for Mac OS X - that's a lot more than 64 bits.

Comment: Mac OS X hardly classifies as *Wintel*.

Comment: Oh - didn't see the `W` there!

Comment: The OP didn't specify the particular compiler used either, so I just assumed MSC/Visual Studio, as being the de-facto default compiler. @Carl: Do you happen to know if in your setup (Clang/Mac OS X) all 16 bytes contribute to a `long double`?

Comment: @IInspectable, no I don't - I guess I could make a test.

Answer (score 1):

Not all rational numbers can be represented accurately as a floating point number; even if the number of significant digits in the source code falls within the limits used by your C++ compiler.

This is due to the fact that the internal representation of a rational number might use a different base from that in the source code. For example

> 0.1<sub>10</sub> = 0.00̅0̅1̅1̅<sub>2</sub>

So mathematically, the binary representation of 0.1<sub>10</sub> has an infinite number of non-zero digits even though the number of decimal places goes nowhere near the number of significant digits available for the internal representation. This leads to the fact that the associative law

> (a + b) - b = a + (b - b)

does not hold anymore, because rounding occurs on the left side when evaluating (a + b), but not on the right side.